# Load second drop box with specific value from first drop box in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to create 2 drop box

- when i select mobile form 1st drop box
- 2nd drop box should open mobile brand list
- if i click Computer in first box
- list of computer brand should open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ajax, it could be something like this

**YOUR HTML**

```
            <select id="combo1" name="combo1" onchange="getvaluesforcombo2($('#combo1').val());">
                <option value=""></option>                      
                <option value="1">Computer</option>                     
                <option value="2">Mobile</option>                       

            </select>
                <select id="combo2" name="combo2">
                    <option value=""></option>                  
                </select>
```

**YOUR JS**

```
function getvaluesforcombo2(valuec1) {
    var postData = {combo1v:combo1v};
    $.post('getvaluefor2.php', postData, function(data) {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        var sel = $("#combo2");
        sel.empty();
        sel.append('<option value=""></option>');
        $.each(obj, function(k, v){
            sel.append('<option value="'+v.Code+'">'+v.Name+'</option>');
        });     
    });
}
```

**AND YOUR PHP**

if (isset($_POST['combo1'])) {
        $combo1= $_POST['combo1'];

```
        $query= $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT type, name FROM mobileandpcbrands WHERE type = :combo1');
        $query->bindValue(':combo1', $combo1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query_pilar->execute();
        //if there is results
        if ($query->rowCount() != 0) {            
        $result = $query->fetchAll();   
        foreach ($result as $results) {
            $rows[] = $results;
         }
        echo json_encode($rows);
        }
```

This is an example i hope this help you